# Как выравнить текст по центру button?

Tags: android

Нужно, чтобы текст был ровно по середине самой кнопки, а не посередине между картинкой и правым краем кнопки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/facebook"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/facebook"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_facebook"
    android:textAllCaps="false"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, легче сделать это в `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_facebook"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/facebook"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Не тестировал, но должно сработать, главное суть поняли...